# Updating AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable with different row/column data

Tags: java, wicket

I have a wicket application with several pages, many of which use an AJAX table to display the data.  But until now their columns have all been static, only the rows change.  The new screen does the following:

- The user enters various query params and clicks submit.  One parameter is a date unit (hours, days, weeks or months) which alongside a from/to date specifies the number of columns to display.
- the data provider gets hold of the params and refreshes the data to display

.. but how to update the columns in the table?

Looking at the DataGridView object in the table code, it looks as if the columns are unchangeable without a major reimplementation of the data table object.  Does anyone have any examples of how to update both the rows and columns of a table when the underlying data changes?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

if you hold a reference to the List that you give the data table in the constructor, in theory you should be able to manipulate it to remove/add columns. however, i am not sure if all the code surrounding the data table takes that usecase into account.

the safest way to do this is to simply to replace the data table instance with a new one that has the correct list of columns.

so something like this

```
addOrReplace(new DataTable("table", ...))
```

whenever the columns need to change.